# ReactJS: Dynamic Navbar Component determined by component prop

Tags: reactjs, react-props

In my app, in the navbar, the menu hamburger and the back button are sharing the same space, and one or the other is shown based on page.

I would like to implement something like :

```
<Nav/>
<Page nav={backButton}/>
```

or

```
<Page nav={Menu}/>
```

Any ideas or links to docs would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I'd try to make this prop driven. Your parent component can pass down a `showBackButton` prop that acts as a switch.

```
{ showBackButton ? <BackButton /> : <HamburgerMenu /> }
```